# Robot Framework Maven plug-in configuration issues

Tags: maven, plugins, robotframework

I have this in my project pom file:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.robotframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>robotframework-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <testCasesDirectory>path/to/testcases</testCasesDirectory>
              <extraPathDirectories>
                <extraPathDirectory>path/to/python/Lib</extraPathDirectory>
              </extraPathDirectories>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

I would like to run the robot tests using

```
mvn robotframework:run
```

But when I do so, it does not recognize my configurations and still go to the default test source folder (/src/test/robotframework/acceptance), and it also does not recognize the added extraPathDirectory.

However, it works when I specify in cmd line

```
mvn robotframework:run -DtestCasesDirectory=path/to/testcases
```

OR when I run

```
mvn install
```

Any ideas why I'm not able to use mvn robotframework:run?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue by simply moving the configuration outside the execution block.

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.robotframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>robotframework-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <testCasesDirectory>path/to/testcases</testCasesDirectory>
          <extraPathDirectories>
            <extraPathDirectory>path/to/python/Lib</extraPathDirectory>
          </extraPathDirectories>
          <libdoc/>
          <testdoc/>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```